# Discord.js cannot find role from guild

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, roles

I'm making a Discord bot using discord.js, however, it is not letting me to get the guild's roles and finding a particular one. It's kind of confusing, so here is the code:

```js
//Note: this is inside a messageReactionAdd event
let guild = reaction.message.guild;
console.log(guild.id);
console.log(guild.roles);
let role = guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == "Member");
reaction.member.roles.add(role);
```

The console spits out the guild ID and a long map of roles and info, but it says that `roles is not a property of undefined` at the line that defines `role`. I have no idea why it's doing this.

Comment: Is this command being tested in a DM? The message object will have no `guild` property if it is in a DM.

Comment: It is in a server. Also I pointed out that it does log the guild ID and role list in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't on the role itself, your problem is on `reaction.member`. Reaction doesn't have member property.

Just change this->

```
reaction.member.roles.add(role);
```

To ([messageReactionAdd](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) has user Parameter) ->

```
guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(role)
```